# Performance cross-company reporting on Exact Online balances

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

To solve consolidation problems with another package, we download all General Ledger transaction lines into an Excel sheet using Invantive Control. In Exact Online we have on each company a classification 2 which contains the code of the client, such as '123400'. There are multiple companies per client.

From another spreadsheet we reference those GL transaction lines using a query such as:

```
SELECT `'Exact transacties$'`.Administratie, `'Exact transacties$'`.Jaar2, `'Exact transacties$'`.Periode, `'Exact transacties$'`.Grootboeknr, `'Exact transacties$'`.Grootboekomschr, `'Exact transacties$'`.Classificatie_code, `'Exact transacties$'`.Zoek_code, `'Exact transacties$'`.Dagboek, `'Exact transacties$'`.Valuta, `'Exact transacties$'`.Bedrag
FROM `'Exact transacties$'` `'Exact transacties$'`
ORDER BY `'Exact transacties$'`.Administratie, `'Exact transacties$'`.Jaar2, `'Exact transacties$'`.Grootboeknr
```

The data source is:

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=PATH\Databestand EOL (bestandsnaam niet wijzigen).xlsm;DefaultDir=PATH;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

However, the consolidation per period across all companies of a client takes 30 minutes per client. Most time is spent thousands of times executing the query on the Exact Online spreadsheet through this formula present in approximately 10 companies x 14 periods x 600 categories = 84.000 cells:

```
=ALS(W$511<=Huidige_periode;V595+(-SOMMEN.ALS(Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Bedrag];Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Administratie];Cliëntnr_EOL1;Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Jaar2];HuidigBoekjaar;Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Periode];W$511;Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Classificatie_code];$B595&"*";Tabel_Query_van_Excel_Files_1[Dagboek];"<900"));0)
```

How can I improve the performance to something less than one minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although technically and functionally correct, the approach you sketch is a bit slow and heavy on the APIs and your CPU. It is better to only retrieve the summed balances from Exact Online and let them do the heavy lifting.

Example:

Choose the right companies to request data on:

```
use
select DIVISIONCLASSES_DIVISIONCLASSNAME_DIVISIONCLASSNAMES_ADMINISTRATION_CODE_ATTR
from   AllAdministrationClassifications 
where  DIVISIONCLASSES_DIVISIONCLASSNAME_NUMBER_ATTR = 2 
and    CODE_ATTR = '123123' -- PUT HERE YOUR CLIENT CODE
```

The `use` statement otherwise than SQL Server allows you to specify multiple partitions (which are companies on Exact Online).

And then fetch the results per GL Account, period and division:

```
select BALANCE
,      PERIODS_YEAR_YEARS_BALANCE_CODE_ATTR
,      DIVISION_HID
,      PERIODS_YEAR_REPORTINGYEAR_ATTR
,      REPORTINGPERIOD_ATTR
from   BalanceLinesPerPeriod
```

In my setup it takes like 10 seconds to retrieve the consolidated amounts across 10 large companies.

There are some table variants available like with cost unit / cost center and year opening / closing balances.